# how to extract src from image in javascript while img tag is coming in js object

Tags: javascript

we have data coming from another application(DB) like below
image file has been stored like

**@1="< img width=498 height=425 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ...">"**

var data = @1


DownloadCode();

i want to download file image file. I am newbie in JS.

Comment: Not too sure ! do you want a physical image? As I can see you have base64 encoded image. So if you want the physical image you need to decode it.

Comment: i tried this code. i need src of image in js variable ........var m,
    urls = [], 
    str = '<img width=498 height=425 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...">',
    rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;

while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
    urls.push( m[1] );
}

console.log( urls );

Comment: The code looks good. and putting everything into an array. you just need to take it from an array ... If you are not using multiple Images avoid array and put into variable

Comment: my string is like str = '<img width=498 height=425 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gAcU29mdHdhcmU6IE1p......hl//2Q">' this reg ex is not working for me. img tag is not closed properly. i think. It is able to render correct.

Comment: Please Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Rahman; It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here how you should do it

```js
var str = '<img width=498 height=425 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...">';

var regex = /<img.*?src="(.*?)"/;
var src = regex.exec(str)[1];

console.log(src);
```